Trying to find a movie from the '80s about warriors put on an island to fight for their country instead of war
As I remember of the story line, each country would send their champion to jungle island to fight it out in a 'winner take all' battle with other country's champions instead of their respective countries going to full scale war. The hero of the story carried two M16s attached together to form a quad M16. The combatants set different jungle traps and snares like pungi sticks, etc. to injure or eliminate their foes and they sleep in the trees. I think they get a 'care package' dropped off to each but can't be sure. 
Kind of like the 2007 Steve Austin movie, 'The Condemned' but with soldiers instead of prisoners.

You might be looking for 1970 TV movie, The Challenge
A short synopsis from Wiki:

An American space satellite lands in an uninhabited area of the
  Pacific. To resolve a dispute that threatens to escalate into all-out
  war, the United States and an unnamed Asian country agree to settle
  the matter with a duel to the death between two champions on a
  deserted tropical island. As Vietnam veteran Jacob Gallery Darren
  McGavin (armed with two Madsen M-50 submachine guns placed side by
  side) and Yuro Mako stalk each other, a bond of respect forms between
  them. However, both countries cheat, each covertly sending a second
  man. Outraged, Gallery and Yuro eliminate their backups and continue
  with their deadly contest. In the end, Gallery emerges victorious, but
  before he can signal the outcome, he succumbs to his wounds.


This may be the movie, it sure sounds like it. I'm going to give you the thumbs up and buy it for my video library... if I can find a copy.
